# Finding a string that matches till http is found

Tags: javascript, regex

```
# Example Agreement

`Purpose` You give a short description.

`Party 1 Name` Seller

`Party 2 Name` Buyer

Speak This is the place where {{document advantage}} goes and this is where {{remove fourth}} goes.  

Then there is this: {{remove last two}}  Then we will have {{standard time}}.

Also, {{remove optional widgets}}.  Then there is also {{standard list}}.

https://github.com
```

I need to get the string from **`Speak** till a \n and http is found ie. I need

> Speak This is the place where {{document advantage}} goes and this is where {{remove fourth}} goes.
>
> Then there is this: {{remove last two}}  Then we will have {{standard time}}.
>
> Also, {{remove optional widgets}}.  Then there is also {{standard list}}.

as the result.

This is what I've tried. but getting the string ending with h with it

[Ss]peak(.+)([\s\S]+?)(\n[http]|$)

Comment: Please share your effort. SO is not **get code for free** site.

Comment: Practise regular expressions and especially have a look at positive lookaheads to solve your problem.

Comment: @Rajesh Added the regex I've tried.

Comment: @Eddi can you please share the regex as I am having problems creating those. Used positive lookaheads but not able to implement it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this RegEx against your test string:

```
([Ss]peak(.|\r|\n)*?(?=http))
```

The part `(?=http)` is the positive lookahead, which asserts that at the end of your string `http` follows.